# Resize image with Picasso library

Tags: android, image, resize, picasso

I am using Picasso to show image from url. My question is how can I resize the image to a variable heigth and width **without crop the image?** Currently when I resize the image without `centerCrop()` it stretches the image. This is what I have:

```
// Get current display dimensions
        DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        width = metrics.widthPixels;
        height = metrics.heightPixels / 2;

// Set image from URL in ImageView
       Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(path)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.loading).resize(width, height)
                .centerCrop().into(image);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a method that will preserve the aspect ratio of your image. I would try

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
            .load(path)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
            .resize(width, height)
            .centerInside()
            .into(image);
```

first, but it's not really clear to me what your exact needs are from your code. Do you want there to be padding around the image?